# Issuing of CAS number without proof of completion of degree

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, transcript-of-records, visa

I hail from Singapore and have applied for the Msc Insurance and Risk Management at City University London and have been offered a place provided I have evidence of the completion of my degree. However, I am unable to provide evidence of the completion of my degree as I am currently in the midst of my Final Year Project (FYP) and will only submit it on 22nd August. Physical evidence of the completion of my degree will only be out in October which would be too late for the start of the program at City University London. Do note that physical evidence of the completion of degree is a requirement set out by UK Visa office, not City University London.

City University London refuses to issue me a [CAS](http://www.studylondon.ac.uk/application-advice/uk-student-visa-information) number because of the reasons mentioned above. CAS number is required for the application of [UK Student Visa (Tier 4)](https://www.gov.uk/tier-4-general-visa/overview).

I have tried the following ways to get City University London to issue me a CAS number

1) Request for the fast track of my academic transcript from my university but it has been rejected by the academic dean of my university.

2) Called [UKVI](https://ukvi-international.faq-help.com/) but even they were unsure of what to do with my situations. The advisor said it may be possible for me to get a [Short-term study visa](https://www.gov.uk/study-visit-visa) before changing to a Student Visa (Tier 4). I am unsure of how this exactly works and if it is even possible. I would appreciate any help.

3) Contact one of the [UK Immigration Advisor](https://www.gov.uk/find-an-immigration-adviser/search-for-an-adviser) for help. Anyone have any idea which one would be best suited for me ??

The best I could do was to get my academic dean to issue a letter stating that he is confident that I will complete my degree given my current stellar results.

I am at my end's wits and would appreciate advice, failure to get a CAS number would mean that I have to wait 1 year to enter City University London which is extremely disruptive to my life

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for legal advice (which we cannot offer) for a specific personal situation (whose answer would apply only to you).